# How did Voyager encounter the Krenim so soon when Kes hadn't ascended?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, timeline

In Voyager's [Before and After](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Before_and_After_%28episode%29), Kes warns Captain Janeway (at the point in her timeline when she is eventually stabilized) about their impending encounter with the [Krenim](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Krenim) "in about six months", for which she was aboard Voyager.

In [The Gift](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Gift_%28episode%29), Kes flings Voyager "ten years closer to home" during her departure from the ship. Soon thereafter, Voyager enters Krenim space, beginning the [Year of Hell](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Year_of_Hell_%28episode%29).

Given that Kes was still aboard Voyager during the "Before and After" encounter with the Krenim, it seems unlikely that the "9.5 thousand light year" boost occurred in that timeline, yet the intervals between Kes' warning and each of the initial Krenim encounters ("Before and After" timeline & both "Year of Hell" timelines) seem comparable.

How did "Before and After" Voyager get all the way to Krenim space (~10 years away) in just a few months?

**Edit:** I'm looking for an in-universe explanation (Jennifer Lien leaving the show didn't necessitate Kes punting Voyager 1/7th of the way home).

Comment: most likely a different boost

Comment: Timey wimey, wibbly wobbly stuff

Comment: Kes' powers were developing before her ascension ("Cold Fire" for example). So we could also ask why they don't seem to be present in "Before and After". It could be that she partially ascended, gave Voyager the boost, but then burnt out.

Answer (score 1):

The out of universe explanation is that Jennifer Lien (Kes) wasn't supposed to be the one leaving the show when Jeri Ryan (Seven) joined the cast. Garrett Wang (Harry Kim) was the one who was supposed to be fired, but he made the 50 Most Beautiful People list in People magazine that year so he was kept and Lien was fired instead. They had already teased the Krenim story line which means they probably already had it planned and decided to do it anyway despite the obvious contradiction.

Comment: That may be true, but it still doesn't answer the question. Was the Harry character supposed to leave in some way that similarly sped up their travel? Also, please list a source for your information.

Comment: The story can be found in a lot of places, but here's one: http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Jennifer_Lien

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that you should include the source in your answer to make it more complete. I wouldn't list Memory Alpha as the source, but instead cite the source listed there directly (Vision of the Future, Stephen Edward Poe, etc.). You should also point out HOW your post answers the question regarding the timeframe in the show - otherwise, it's just pointing out un-related, albeit interesting, information.

Answer (score 1):

There were a LOT of rumors going around at the time, ranging from that she'd quit cause her character wasn't being developed enough to that she'd gotten into a huge fight with a crew member and was fired. The character of Kes ascending was sort of a last minute thing. It was stated in the book *A Vision of the Future - Star Trek: Voyager*, that the producers decided not to renew [Jennifer Lien](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jennifer_Lien)'s contract so that they could bring in the cheaper (salary wise) Jeri Ryan. They'd needed to free up some money, and initially it was going to be Garrett Wang. But after he made 50 Most Beautiful People in People Magazine, so the producers decided to keep him.

In universe, it could be stated that due to her going "back in time" changed the timeline in such a manner that even though the timing of meeting the Krenim was right, it needed to happen that she pushed them to it. Since Janeway knew about the upcoming encounter, perhaps she'd slowed down in an effort to not appear hostile to them so that they wouldn't experience the year of hell.